# Plugin [id: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android', version: '1.7.20', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources

Tags: android, kotlin

I installed Android Studio and made the new Project with basic setting.
And then this error occurred.

- Exception is:
  org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin [id: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android', version: '1.7.20', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

I just set the HTTP proxy setting.
What should I do other setting?

Below is build.gradle file

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.3.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.3.1' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.20' apply false
}
```

I tried Invalidate cache, restart but it still not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by not adding JRE certificate.
I registered it by entering the command below in the cmd window.

```
keytool -import -file XXX.crt -keystore ${ANDROID_STUDIO}/jre/jre/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit
```